# How to avoid by displaying loadtime again and again?

Tags: php

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

//PAGE LOAD TIME
    if(!curl_errno($ch)){
            $cinfo =  curl_getinfo($ch); 
            echo 'Page loaded in '.$cinfo['total_time'].' seconds'."<br/><br/>";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

whenever I am calling curl function its displaying loadtime and I cant even create one more curl function if we can create how to create multiple curl function with same url.?

Answer (score 0):

```
$loadMessageDisplayed = FALSE;

function whatever() {
  global $loadMessageDisplayed;

  ...

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  //PAGE LOAD TIME
  if(!curl_errno($ch) && !$loadMessageDisplayed){
        $cinfo =  curl_getinfo($ch); 
        echo 'Page loaded in '.$cinfo['total_time'].' seconds'."<br/><br/>";
        $loadMessageDisplayed = TRUE;
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: i want display only once. how to do that

Comment: Thank you. its displaying out of my field

Comment: <div class="col-md-8">
    <?php $site=$_POST["url"];
      $d=file_get_contents_curl($site);  
    ?>
</div> i am calling it this division but noting is visible